# How to write under graph in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Please can any one help me to write under the graph in latex like this graph

[image]

i used the tikzpicture to ddraw any graph 
this is

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=4em, row sep=9ex, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=8pt] (M) {
    \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{1}$}] (V1) {}; 
    &  \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{2}$}] (V2) {};
  & & \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{1}$}] (V11) {};
   & \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{2}$}] (V21) {};
    \\
    \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=2pt,yshift=4pt]v$_{3}$}] (V3) {}; & \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{4}$}] (V4) {};
    & & \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=2pt,yshift=4pt]v$_{3}$}] (V31) {}; &  \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{4}$}] (V41) {};



    \\
};
\draw (V3) --  (V1);
\draw (V3) -- node[below]{G} (V4);
\draw (V2) --  (V4);
\draw (V3) --  (V2);
\draw (V11) --  (V21);
\draw (V11) --  (V41);


\end{tikzpicture} 



    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth ]{}
    \caption{A graph with it's complement \label{13}}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: You could write under it directly in `tikz` or use an external package like `stackengine`.  However, for us to help you, you should add a minimum working example of code to show what you have achieved so far.

Comment: i divided the code in three comment because the size of it is big

Comment: You can edit your original question to add the code, rather than supplying it in comments.  Also, a "working" example means to begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`

Comment: Please add your code to your question, you must become familiar with [our format](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: ok i add code of different graph but is related to my question

Comment: When you copy code into a question, highlight the code block and press the `{}` button at the top of the edit box.  This will indent the code 4 spaces, which has the effect of displaying it to the read as code, rather than text.  I did this for you already, but for next time...

Comment: In any case, `\node[below]  at (current bounding box.south) {...};` might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use two `\matrix`es instead of one. It's easy to place the second one relative to the first one, with the help of the `positioning` library, and the labels can be added by using a `label` for the `\matrix`.

Note that for `node` `label`s, you should use the syntax `label={[<options>]<position>:<label>}`. In this case you don't need any options I think, just do e.g. `label=left:$v_1$`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   mypoint/.style={fill,draw,inner sep=0pt,label distance=2pt,minimum size=3pt,circle},
   % define a style for the matrix
   mymatrix/.style={
     column sep=4em, row sep=9ex,
     % makes each cell a node that is automatically named, so don't use \node ...
     matrix of nodes,
     % applies the mypoint style to each node in the matrix
     nodes=mypoint}]

\matrix[
  mymatrix,
  % add label below the matrix
  label=below:$G$
]
% give the matrix a name
 (M)
{
    |[label=left:$v_{1}$]| & |[label=right:$v_{2}$]| \\
    |[label=left:$v_{3}$]| & |[label=right:$v_{4}$]| \\
};

\matrix[
  mymatrix,
  % position it relative to the first matrix
  right=3cm of M,
  label=below:$G2$
]
 (M2)
{
    |[label=left:$v_{1}$]| & |[label=right:$v_{2}$]| \\
    |[label=left:$v_{3}$]| & |[label=right:$v_{4}$]| \\
};

% draw lines in left matrix
% the name of the matrix is M, so each node is named
% M-<row number>-<column number>
\draw (M-1-1) -- (M-2-1) -- (M-1-2) -- (M-2-2) -- (M-2-1);

% lines in right matrix
\draw (M2-1-2) -- (M2-1-1) -- (M2-2-2);

\end{tikzpicture} 

\bigskip


    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth ]{example-image-16x10}
    \caption{A graph with its complement \label{13}}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```